# CSV file into list - user input determines what row to output to the user

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to make a program that takes any CSV.file and puts it into a list to read from. The row for the CSV.file will be displayed to the user for them to choose what they would like to do. Their decision will take them to a specific row and it will keep doing this till the user ends the program. The row they are taken to needs to be decided by the CSV.file and not user input. In the CSV.file there will be numbers at the end of the row showing which row to print out based on the user input. For example eat, sleep, run, walk 1, 2, 3, 4. So if they choose eat print row 1 if they choose sleep print row 2 and so on. But it cannot be hard coded because different CSV.files can be used in the program.

So im not sure if I should take the CSV.file and separate the integers from the text into two separate lists and then reference and have them reference each other?

Comment: Please, provide more details of what you're trying to accomplish, and also, some code of what you have tried before asking for help, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, avoid asking low-effort questions

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have a good plan for thinking

```
import csv
# For the average
from statistics import mean 

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open("pr.file1.csv") as f:
        red=csv.reader(f)
        for row in red:
            name=row[0]
            aray1=row[1:]
            aray2=[]
            for number in aray1:
                aray2.append(int(number))
            return mean(aray2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the CSV file into a data frame then you'll have all the info in a list like data structure. Use pandas CSV => to dataframe. Use pandas.df.iloc[0] to get the row and specific column. This is what I understood from your question. It will go something like below:

---

```
import pandas as pd

def getRow(df, i, j): # use this function loop over it to get a specific row 
    print(df.iloc[i]) 
    print(df.iloc[i, j])

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
while(True):
   i = int(input("Row Index")) # Loop over these two lines to continuously do that
   j = int(input("Column Index"))
   getRow(df, i, j)
```